# Regex replace all groups of pipes

Tags: regex

I need to write a regular expression to select all pipe values in a string, no matter the number in a row. For example:

Hello||everyone||||reading ||||||||my|||post|on||stack-overflow||||||||||

The idea being I need to replace all groups of pipes with a single value. Everything apart from pipes should be left untouched

My regular expression skills are limited, but so far I have created: "(\|)*$"

However this only selects the group of pipes at the end and not the others. Thanks in advance for any help.

EDIT: I should note I'm using Regex.Replace() in C#

Comment: Remove the `$` sign from the regex.

Comment: Voting to close as _typo_.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, tried it and it removes all the pipes, however it affects every individual character also

Comment: @James Then use `@"\|+"` or `@"\|{2,}"`

Answer (score 1):

You should use `Regex.Split` instead `Regex.Replace`

```
splitArray = Regex.Split(subjectString, @"\|+");
```

But if you prefer replacing:

```
resultString = Regex.Replace(subjectString, @"\|+", "");
```

And if you want to leave just one pipe (I couldn't figure this out from your question) you can:

```
resultString = Regex.Replace(subjectString, @"\|+", "|");
```

Comment: May I wonder why `Split` is preferred to `Replace`? And why don't you use in such case just `subjectString.Split(new[] { '|' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)`?

Comment: Sure, he just need the value between the pipes.

Comment: I don't see the requirement to extract values between pipes.

Comment: @UlugbekUmirov Is the question clear for you? if so, please tell me what I'm missing.

Comment: OP stated clearly that he just wants to replace all `|`s with single value. `Hello||world|` becomes `Hello|world|` or `"Hello$world$` (that is your last `.Replace` expression). He didn't say anything about values between pipes. If we split and join using `|` we will lose leading and trailing pipes, but he may have requirement to keep them.

Comment: @UlugbekUmirov it seems that I've already posted the answer, tks!

Answer (score 0):

This should do it.

```
string input = "Hello||everyone||||reading ||||||||my|||post|on||stack-overflow||||||||||";
string yourSingleValue = "someValue";
Regex rePipeStripper = new Regex(@"\|+",RegexOptions.None);
string output = rePipeStripper.Replace(input, yourSingleValue);
```